# How can I extract the number of items with the same value in a list?

Tags: c#, winforms, list

I have multiple list of int for the ID that are merged together. i need to get the ID that matches the total number of duplicates with a certain number. for example:

```
int g=3;
List<int> mainlist = new List<int>();
List<int> list1 = new List<int>{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
List<int> list2 = new List<int>{2,3,4,5,7,8,9};
List<int> list3 = new List<int>{1,3,5,6,7,9};

mainlist = list1.Concat(list2).Concat(list3).Tolist();
```

I want to get  the ID where the number of duplicate is equal to g

Comment: What do you want as a result? It should be like `{3, 3, 3}` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group your `mainlist` and select only these groups where `Count() == g`:

```
var IDs = mainlist.GroupBy(n => n).Where(n => n.Count() == g).Select(n => n.Key);
```

Answer (score 1):

`GroupBy` is the best choice in this case,anyway this is an alternative:

```
 mainlist.Where(x => mainlist.Count(i => x == i) == g).ToList();
```